# Tag synonym request: [return-value-optimization]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [return-value-optimization](/questions/tagged/return-value-optimization) has the following variations:

- [copy-elision](/questions/tagged/copy-elision)
- [rvo](/questions/tagged/rvo)
- [nrvo](/questions/tagged/nrvo): the named version.

They're all just different terms for the same thing. All of them have fairly few hits, but [return-value-optimization](/questions/tagged/return-value-optimization) has the most, so I suggest that it becomes the parent.